# Ubuntu Server - How to Remove Desktop

Tags: server, desktop-environments

I installed Ubuntu Server 18.04 LTS as a VM. Then I installed Unity desktop with --no-install-recommends as in below command:

```
sudo apt install --no-install-recommends ubuntu-unity-desktop
```

Now I want to remove desktop and return my good old terminal screen. I tried removing desktop with following command and reboot but nothing was changed after reboot.

```
sudo apt remove --purge ubuntu-unity-desktop
```

Is there a way to remove desktop totally?

Comment: Yes it works Thomas, thank you very much, appreciated.

Comment: You're welcome.  I've converted my comment to an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ubuntu-unity-desktop` is a metapackage that has dependencies on other packages.  Simply removing the metapackage doesn't remove the dependencies.

Run `sudo apt autoremove --purge` after you remove the metapackage, because the other dependencies weren't manually defined for installation but were instead included because `ubuntu-unity-desktop` needed them, you need to autoremove the 'now not needed' dependencies pulled in.

Answer (score 3):

For the record - with Ubuntu 18.04 slowly losing importance:

On Ubuntu 22.04 i had to remove the package "**`ubuntu-desktop-minimal`**" followed by "`apt-get autoremove`" to remove 158 desktop related packages.