# Can unattended upgrade shutdown my Ubuntu Server?

Tags: shutdown, systemd, unattended-upgrades

My server unexpectedly powered down today. From syslog, it seems like it might have been the unattended upgrade service:

```
Nov 22 15:23:25 lynx systemd[1]: unattended-upgrades.service: Succeeded.
Nov 22 15:23:25 lynx systemd[1]: Removed slice system-modprobe.slice.
Nov 22 15:23:25 lynx systemd[1]: Stopped target Graphical Interface.
Nov 22 15:23:25 lynx systemd[1]: Stopped target Multi-User System.
Nov 22 15:23:25 lynx systemd[1]: Stopped target Login Prompts.
Nov 22 15:23:25 lynx systemd[1]: Stopped target Host and Network Name Lookups.
Nov 22 15:23:25 lynx systemd[1]: Stopped target Timers.
...
etc
```

The omitted parts are a list of various services that systemd is shutting down. If I look at the output of `last`:

```
$ last -x | head | tac
...
shutdown system down  5.4.0-90-generic Mon Nov 22 15:23 - 17:14  (01:51)
reboot   system boot  5.4.0-90-generic Mon Nov 22 17:14   still running
runlevel (to lvl 5)   5.4.0-90-generic Mon Nov 22 17:15   still running
```

I can see that the shutdown was properly logged to the system, and then you can see 2 hours later when I noticed the machine was down and rebooted it. My question is two fold - Why did this happen, and how do I configure this? I've been running this machine for years and I don't think I can recall it ever shutting down for an update before. The logs make me *think* it was unattended upgrade that did this, but I'm not sure how to verify that. If I understood how to configure unattended upgrade's settings/options I might notice something that controls it rebooting or shutting down, which is why I want to know how to do that. I'd prefer to either disable this (no shutdown) or change it to reboot (if the machine is on, I want it to stay on!). Any suggestions?

Comment: A server occasionally reboots because of unattended upgrades, but (1) it always restarts, doesn't just shut down; (2) it happens at 3:00 AM, certainly not in the middle of the day; and (3) you get a warning every hour on the hour the day before it happens, whenever you use a terminal. Moreover, you get an email warning if you have configured these. So I don't think this is an unattended-upgrades issue.

Comment: I'm happy to post more of the syslog, but I don't see anything else that looks remotely related :(

Comment: Have you looked  at [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1308468/ubuntu-server-shuts-down-daily) question? Does `sudo journalctl  -b -1 -e ` give any interesting output?